# Implementation of levenberg marquardt optimization in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, levenberg-marquardt

I wanted to check if the Levenberg Marquardt optimization has been implemented in TensorFlow. I have typically used Adam optimizer in the past but I read that Levenberg Marquardt optimization works better for non-linear datasets. Does anybody know if this is available in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Levenberg marquardt` optimizer is available in `TensorFlow` inside `Tensorflow_Graphics` module and can be accessed using `tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt`. For this, you need to install **tensorflow-graphics** first. Please check the code below:

```
!pip install tensorflow-graphics
import tensorflow_graphics as tfg
from tensorflow_graphics.math.optimizer import levenberg_marquardt
```